# Abstract objects setting attributes in base class

Tags: java, lombok, builder

Hello I have the following class structure -

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
abstract class A {
   String a;
}


@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class B extends A {
  String b;
}


public A setAField(final A aObj, final String setA) {
  return aObj.toBuilder().a(setA).build();
}
```

The IDE is showing error as its not able to find the toBuilder() method. Do I need to cast to concrete before calling the toBuilder()?

Comment: Lombok has a feature called "delombok", replacing the annotations with the code normally generated at compile-time. I suggest taking a look at what lombok generates. --- If you are still learning the language, I recommend to not use advanced tools like lombok; they will do more harm than good.

Answer (score 1):

`toBuilder()` is an *instance method*. To use the static method for the builder, use `builder()`:

```
A.builder().a(setA).build();
```

Or use the `aObj` instance in your method:

```
aObj.toBuilder().a(setA).build();
```

Comment: My bad I made a mistake in the question. I am using the `aObj.toBuilder().a(setA).build()`.  The ide is not able to recognise this.